# Javascript Help - prevent duplicate characters in textbox

Tags: javascript, textbox, duplicates

Looking for a bit of help to modify some already-working JavaScript.

I am using a piece of JavaScript along with a filtered textbox, the filtered text box only allows {1234567890,-}

The below JavaScript works and prevents the user from entering more than 1 decimal 
I want to also add a dash/minus {-} to the allowed characters and prevent duplicates

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function PreventDuplicateDecimal(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        var itemdecimal = evt.srcElement.value.split('.');
        if (itemdecimal.length > 1 && charCode == 46)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

I have tried adding;

I have tried adding
`var itemdash = evt.srcElement.value.split('-');`
and adding it as a 'or' statement but no luck

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance
Paul

Comment: So the user is supposed to enter valid decimal numbers in this box?

Comment: Yes valid decimal numbers so {1234567890,-}
iI cannot use a regular expressions in this case as I have other decimal formatting firing from .net code-behind
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if(evt.srcElement.value.indexOf(".") > -1) {
    if (charCode === 46) {
        return false;
    }
}
if(evt.srcElement.value.indexOf("-") > -1) {
    if (charCode === 45) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```