# Prevent duplicate comma from being typed into Input Text Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a textbox to collect numbers only, separated by a comma. No other characters, not even spaces, are allowed. Only 0-9 and a comma.

The following function serves my purpose, but I'd like to now prevent a duplicate comma from being entered.

Correct
e.g. 22,444,2,444

Incorrect
e.g. 22,,444,2,444 OR 22,,444,,2,,444

Here is the code I'm using for limiting the field to numbers, and allowing only a comma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#customPrices").keypress(function (e) {


if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && String.fromCharCode(e.which) != ',' && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57))
{

//display error message
if($( "#errmsg" ).is(':hidden'))
{
$( "#errmsg" ).fadeIn();
}
return false;

}

});
});
```

I've found something that may be able to work at the following link:
[Javascript Help - prevent duplicate characters in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000283/javascript-help-prevent-duplicate-characters-in-textbox)

The example there needs to prevent a hyphen, which is charCode 45. A comma is charCode 44....

But I'm not sure of how to implement it into my current code...

Any help would be really loved, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your position, I would not try to validate the key press, but rather **validate the content of the text box when the user changes it**.

This can e.g. be achieved using a regular expression:

```js
function validate() {
  var input = document.getElementById('inputField').value;

  if(input.match(/,{2,}/g)) {
    // the user entered a duplicate comma
    alert('No duplicate commas allowed!');
  }
}
```

```html
<input oninput='validate()' id='inputField' />
```

---

You can also extend the regular expression to **check the input for characters other than the numbers 0 to 9 and commas**:

```
/(,{2,}|[^,0-9])/g
```

This will also report e.g. `22,44,d,17` as invalid.

Comment: I tried this at first, but although it was detecting the duplicate comma, and throwing the alert, it was still allowing the comma to be entered anyway. I settled for sarath's answer, but thank you so much for your reply! If there is any way to use yours and prevent the comma from being entered, I would really love to know.

Comment: I had to eventually use your answer, because the previous one did not agree with all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
add the below condition:
1) take the existing value
2) check the last char is (,) and current char also (,) and validate
 var customPrices = $("#customPrices").val();

String.fromCharCode(e.which) == ',' && String.fromCharCode(e.which) == 
customPrices.charAt(customPrices.length-1)

or 
String.fromCharCode(e.which) == ',' && customPrices.charAt(customPrices.length-1) == ','
```

Comment: Thank you thank you so much, I used the second one and it worked beautifully!